# Is there any way to optimize this method?

Tags: java, methods, refactoring

I have this code, basically check is there any `null`. I used *SonarQube* and I have to optimize as much as I can, I feel is ok but i have to try. Any ideas?

In the following code, each `fila` has simple records of `Strings`.

```
public boolean isColumnNull(DbfReader reader, int[] pos) {

    Object[] fila = null;
    boolean isNull = false;
    int cont = 0;

    while (cont < pos.length) {

        while ((fila = reader.nextRecord()) != null) {

            for (int j = 0; j < fila.length; j++) {

                if ((j == pos[0] || j == pos[1]) && fila[j] == null) {

                    isNull = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            cont++;
        }
    }

    return isNull;
}
```

Comment: That code looks wrong. It's going to read (at least) `pos.length` number of records, but only uses `pos[0]` and `pos[1]`, regardless of array length? *Huh?!?* --- Also, if `nextRecord()` returns null, that presumably means end-of-data, so the outer loop will try again, and it'll loop forever.

Comment: So `pos` holds the positions in a record to check for a null field, I figured that much out. But why the outer loop of `while(cont < pos.length){ ... }` ?

Comment: @Turing85 ["It's important to keep in mind the full quote"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/80092/139641).

Comment: `pos.length` always is 2, the values change. `while(cont < pos.length){ ... }` because there are more columns but I´m always intersted in 2 which come from the array, culd be 3 and 7 for example

Comment: But you just want to check if any record has `null` in the columns indicated in the `pos` array (eg. column `3`  and `7`), right? You don't care about any other columns.

Comment: yes, I´m realizing this while is not neccesary, thanks

Comment: @AndyTurner ["*The real problem is that programmers have spent
far too much time worrying about efficiency in the
wrong places and at the wrong times; premature
optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it)
in programming.*"](http://delivery.acm.org/10.1145/370000/361612/a1974-knuth.pdf?ip=89.0.113.76&id=361612&acc=OPEN&key=4D4702B0C3E38B35%2E4D4702B0C3E38B35%2E4D4702B0C3E38B35%2E6D218144511F3437&__acm__=1545861914_732c1e06c989119a008ed179e9d13754). That's why I linked the source in my comment :)

Comment: There is a bit of nesting of while, for-loops and _if_. You can refactor the code and use a method to work with logic associated with an inner loop. This is for readability. Also, you can try using a _label_ for the loop you are trying to break - so that the `break` can be identified with that labeled loop.

Answer (score 1):

The inner for loop can be replaced with

```
if ((pos[0] < fila.length && fila[pos[0]] == null) || 
    (pos[1] < fila.length && fila[pos[1]] == null)) {
    isNull = true;
    break;
}
```

As suggested by Andy Turner both pos[0] and pos[1] should be checked that they are >= 0, this should be done once before the while loop starts.

Comment: And, of course, you could then break (or return), since `isNull` never becomes false again.

Comment: @AndyTurner Yes of course, I read isNull as being per record but it is for the whole method. Thanks.

Comment: (and check that `pos[n] >= 0`)